# SQL Server : trigger update column of table after other table insert or update a record

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

I have 2 tables, `ShareButton` and `SharePage`.

`ShareButton` table:

```
+----+---------------+---------------+
| ID | Name          | TotalShare    |
+----+---------------+---------------+
|  1 | Facebook      |      0        |
|  2 | Twitter       |      0        |
+----+---------------+---------------+
```

`SharePage` table:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+---------------+
| ID |        URL         | Share | ShareButtonID |
+----+--------------------+-------+---------------+
| 1  | www.abc.xyz/page1  |    3  |      1        |
| 2  | www.abc.xyz/page1  |   14  |      2        |
| 3  | www.abc.xyz/page2  |    6  |      1        |
| 4  | www.abc.xyz/page2  |   10  |      2        |
+----+--------------------+-------+---------------+
```

After insert or update a record in the `SharePage` table, `TotalShare` column  of `ShareButton` is updated

```
update ShareButton 
set TotalShare = (sum(Share) from SharePage where "ShareButtonID" = ShareButtonID of updated/inserted record)) 
where ID = ShareButtonID of updated/inserted record)`
```

Thank for reading!

Comment: Why even save this information? Why not query it with an aggregate query when you need it?

Comment: You are overdoing things + Why trigger? You can simply update the parent table in the stored proc that modifies `SharePage` table.

Comment: Thank all. That is best and simple way :D

Answer (score 0):

Let me start my answer by saying I agree with Mureinik. Unless you have a really bad performance hit getting the sum of shares using a simple group by query, I wouldn't recommend saving that sum in the `ShareButton` table.

If you really want a trigger to calculate it, I guess the simplest way to do it is this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trSharePage_Changed ON SharePage 
FOR UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE
AS

UPDATE buttons
SET TotalShare = SumOfShares
FROM ShareButton buttons
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ShareButtonID, SUM(Share) As SumOfShares
    FROM SharePage 
    GROUP BY ShareButtonID
) pages ON buttons.ID = pages.ShareButtonID
```

Note that this trigger will be fired after any insert, update or delete statement on table SharePage will  be completed. Since it's an after trigger, you don't need to deal with the inserted and deleted tables at all.